# Why does my PHP/MYSQL request take up to 5mins to load?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, geocoding

TL;DR - Used `JOIN` as substitute for inefficient `IN`

I have a program that returns units that are listed as 'covering' any locations that are within a certain distance of an original locations.

That is, the user searches for a region, distance from and category. The query then returns all offices that cover any of the regions that are within the searched distance of the original region.

There are two tables, one with 'publications/offices' and one with the regions covered by each publication, linked by their index. In the regions database, there is an entry for each region that the publication covers.

The problem is, when I run a query it takes up to 3mins to return the results?

I'm using a shared cloud server, but I feel like the code is inefficient.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <?php 
                    }     
                      $sql=mysql_query("select * from publications where ".$subwhereclause." AND publications.entry_id in (( SELECT regions_to_publications.pub_id  from regions_to_publications WHERE ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) *(1.6) < ".$_REQUEST["distance"].")) ") or die(mysql_error());

                      ?>
                    <?php while($row3= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {?>
                    <div class="result-entry-card">

                    <p class="card-title"><?php echo $row3['entry_name'] ;?></p>
                    <p class="card-cat"><?php echo $row3['entry_category'];?></p>

                    <p><?php echo $row3['entry_phone'];?> - <a href="mailto:<?php echo $row3['entry_email'];?>"><?php echo $row3['entry_email'];?></a></p>

                     <p><a href="http://<?php echo $row3['entry_website'];?>">Email</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Any ideas why it would take so long to run through? I'm still learning!

UPDATE: I ran `EXPLAIN` on the following code (substituting variables).

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM publications
WHERE publications.entry_category
IN (
 ".newspapers."
)
AND publications.entry_id
IN (
(

SELECT regions_to_publications.pub_id
FROM regions_to_publications
WHERE (
(
ACOS( SIN( - 33.8683 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( lat * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( - 33.8683 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( lat * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( 151.2086 - lon ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )
) *60 * 1.1515
) * ( 1.6 ) <  "1000"
)
)
```

These were the results.

```
| id |select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
| 1 | PRIMARY | publications | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 621 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | regions_to_publications | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 84173 | Using where
```

For anyone wondering, I looked through these results and redid the search as follows, utilizing `JOIN` instead of `IN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM publications
JOIN regions_to_publications ON entry_id = pub_id
WHERE (
(
ACOS( SIN( - 33.8683 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( regions_to_publications.lat * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( - 33.8683 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( regions_to_publications.lat * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( 151.2086 - regions_to_publications.lon ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )
) *60 * 1.1515
) * ( 1.6 ) <  "1000"

AND

publications.entry_category
IN (
"radio"
)

GROUP BY publications.entry_id
```

Comment: Psst... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: The reason is probably because of the use of `in` with a subquery.  In older versions of MySQL this optimized very poorly.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz , I will definitely look into that for the next iteration! Looks like it might be a gold mine...

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks a heap. I've replaced the `IN` with a `JOIN` function and the script runs super fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL contains some major vulnerabilities with `$_REQUEST["distance"]` and possibly `$subwhereclause`, depending on it's origins.

Also, consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or mysqli because of this:

> Deprecated: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Anyways, to answer your question, try using `explain` and see what mysql tells you. It will tell you what indexes are being used and how many rows are being scanned. That should set you on the right track.

I would recommend doing this from your Shell or PHPMyAdmin.

Good luck!

P.S. - To use `explain` simply add it to the beginning of a `SELECT` statement.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=value
```

Edit - I see you have ran an `EXPLAIN` and posted the results.

`possible_keys` and `key` are pretty important (key is the same thing as index). The explain is analyzing each query (since there is a subquery).

`possible_keys` being NULL is like Mysql saying "I looked at each index to see if I can use it, but none of them worked". Usually this means you had to do a full table scan (rows is the number of rows that needed to be scanned).

The subquery is especially suffering from the lack of a useable key. It had to scan *84173*
rows. Since your query is not exactly simple, this is probably a pretty intense scan on each row.

Take a look at your indexes and figure out why mysql can't use them. The reason I recommend doing this in PHPMyAdmin or the Shell is now you can easily change the query and see if the index works. Try and simplify everything down first and then build it back up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've run EXPLAIN, but I'm a little unsure of how to interpret the results. I've updated original post with results.

Comment: Thanks so much! I used a combination of your technique and the `JOIN` function instead of IN and the search is essentially instant now!  Many many thanks.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to remove those vulnerabilities before making the script live :)